# Change the levels of multiple factors that start_with the same pattern in R

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, tidyverse, forcats

I have a long data frame with thousands of observations, but for demonstration purposes I am presenting this

```
df <- data.frame(col1=rep(c("A","B","C"),3),
                 col2=c("10.01","10.02","10.03","100.1","100.2","100.3","12.1","12.2","12.3"))

 col1  col2
1    A 10.01
2    B 10.02
3    C 10.03
4    A 100.1
5    B 100.2
6    C 100.3
7    A  12.1
8    B  12.2
9    C  12.3

df <- df %>% 
  mutate_all(., as.factor)

levels(df$col2)
"10.01" "10.02" "10.03" "100.1" "100.2" "100.3" "12.1"  "12.2"  "12.3"
```

I want to change the order of the levels in the col2 and be like this

```
"10.01" "10.02" "10.03" "12.1"  "12.2"  "12.3" "100.1" "100.2" "100.3"
```

Any help or comment are highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `forcats::fct_inseq`:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate_all(., as.factor) %>% 
  mutate(col2 = fct_inseq(df$col2))
```

Output:

```
levels(df$col2)
[1] "10.01" "10.02" "10.03" "12.1"  "12.2"  "12.3"  "100.1" "100.2" "100.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `gtools::mixedsort` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%  mutate(across(.fns = ~factor(., gtools::mixedsort(unique(.)))))

str(df)
#'data.frame':  9 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ col1: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
# $ col2: Factor w/ 9 levels "10.01","10.02",..: 1 2 3 7 8 9 4 5 6

sapply(df, levels)
#$col1
#[1] "A" "B" "C"

#$col2
#[1] "10.01" "10.02" "10.03" "12.1"  "12.2"  "12.3"  "100.1" "100.2" "100.3"
```